# ContentResolver openInputStream() throws FileNotFound on existing file

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I have this apparently simple code

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File testfile = new File(path,"image.jpg");

Log.d(TAG,"testfile: " + testfile + " exists: " + testfile.exists());

Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(testfile);
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
InputStream istr = cr.openInputStream(uri);
```

The output is:

```
testfile: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/image.jpg exists: true
```

The uri value is `file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/image.jpg`. Looks like the same file, but the openInputStream() throws an FileNotFoundException.

Any idea why? This is on Android 6.0.1.

Comment: Do you have a `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` `<uses-permission>` element in your manifest? If your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher, have you requested the permission at runtime? See https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/31/hey-where-did-my-permission-go.html for more possibilities.

Comment: Yes, correct. targetSdkVersion is 23 and I did not request the permission. Thanks. Was confused because it worked in the past...

Answer (score 1):

Add this permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

When targetSdkVersion is 23 or above (Android 6), putting this in the AndroidManifest.xml is not enough and you have to request the permission at runtime.

Comment: This is in my AndroidManifest.xml, but as mentioned by 'CommonsWare' in a comment to my question, I increased targetSdkVersion 23 and now have to request the permission during runtime. I've added this to your answer.